# Site links have started giving 403 errors through Facebook debugger

Tags: facebook, joomla, http-status-code-403

Over the last couple of days, I've noticed some odd behaviour in Facebook debugger (also used for Threads).

For instance, this URL refuses to show a preview in debugger:

https://www.hot-dinners.com/Features/Hot-Dinners-recommends/new-london-restaurants-opening-in-march-2024

With the error coming back: URL returned a bad HTTP response code (i.e. a 403 error).

It's happening with other pages too - some of which appeared to work in the last crawl. I talked to the host and they say that nothing has changed their end. Can anyone work out if there's an issue with this page that I'm not seeing - or point me in a direction to get more info? Thanks!

Direct link to debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hot-dinners.com%2FFeatures%2FHot-Dinners-recommends%2Fnew-london-restaurants-opening-in-march-2024

Comment: _"Can anyone work out if there's an issue with this page that I'm not seeing"_ - no, we can not tell from the outside, why _your_ system has decided to respond to the request from the Facebook scraper, with 403 Forbidden. Your system is a basically a "black box" to us, we don't have access to any of the coding, log files etc. _"or point me in a direction to get more info?"_ - I'd try and see if you can reproduce the issue, when _you_ are making a request, that uses the same User-Agent header, as the Facebook scraper does. And if you can - then you need to debug, _why_ the 403 happens.

Comment: Yes, fair point - and thanks will follow the debugging advice.

Comment: I can see the same issue here. And I can see each and every request coming from the fb bot and they get 200 OK, so definitely not a problem here:
`173.252.87.2 - - [01/Mar/2024:13:18:37 +0000] "GET /some_path HTTP/1.1" 200 6079 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" "-"`

Answer (score 1):

General update to this. The issue was indeed on Facebook's side. You need to explicitly allow "facebookexternalhit" in your robots.txt. It will take a few hours for Facebook to crawl the new robots file but it will eventually work.

Answer (score 0):

The first step that you need to do is to check the logs - why are they returning 403 for facebook? Is the scraper IP blocked? Is the bot blocked in the .htaccess file? Is it a modsecurity rule that was recently installed by your host? Do you have a security plugin that might be causing it? If you do, try disabling this plugin for a few moments and see if this works.

If you can't find the traffic anywhere in your logs, then it means that the traffic is blocked at a higher level, possibly by your hosting platform's data center firewall. It might also be a hiccup somewhere which will resolve itself.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, will work my way though this. No changes in the past few days so it feels unlikely it's a plugin (but will still do some trials of disabling some all the same).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a FB error, we are experiencing the same issue since yesterday. Our server and pages are ok.

Comment: Ah - useful to know that someone else is getting this. Some pages display OK in Facebook, but still throw the 403, others show nothing at all. Very odd.

Comment: I am also seeing these for the last week or so

Comment: It's looking more and more lke a facebook issue - noticed a few people starting to raise it there: https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/825654679324994/